# is plotkml no longer updated for current R release and if so how can i install it anyway?

Tags: r

This is my r version: 4.2.0

But the last updated file for this package in the archives is plotKML_0.8-2.tar.gz from 2021-10-30.

I downloaded it from the archive but R studio still doesn't allow me to install it. The error I get is : ERROR: dependencies 'gstat', 'colorRamps', 'pixmap', 'XML', 'dismo', 'landmap', 'aqp', 'spacetime', 'plyr', 'stars' are not available for package 'plotKML'

What should I do to install it?

Comment: Hi! The error states that you need to install some packages in order to install plotkml. Did you already install them? For example using `install.packages('gstat', 'colorRamps', 'pixmap', 'XML', 'dismo', 'landmap', 'aqp', 'spacetime', 'plyr', 'stars')`